# Prevent UIButton's setTitle:forState: animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, uibutton

I am using a `NSTimer` to update a `UIButton`'s title every second.

It works but the text in the title blinks (animates to alpha `0` and back) automatically.

I tried to use `button.layer.removeAllAnimations()` with no luck, and no exceptions, so QuartzCore seems to be correctly linked.

---

Current non-working paranoid code:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    button.setTitle(time, forState: .Normal)
    button.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Did you try to wrap it with `UIView`'s `performWithoutAnimation(_ actionsWithoutAnimation: () -> Void)` (iOS >= 7)? Or `setAnimationsEnabled(_ enabled: Bool)`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Make sure your button is a "custom" button and not a "system" button.

If you created it on a storyboard, then just change the Button Type. If you created it programmatically, then it should be:

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Comment: Nice! Yet I can't understand why a system button refuses to obey to standard UIKit orders.

Comment: This is unbelievable. I had an issue where setting the title was taking a long time. I debugged and tested things for many hours. I saw this answer and thought it couldn’t work…. It worked. Now my button updates quickly. Can anyone explain why this works?

Answer (score 19):

I’ve made a Swift extension to do this:

```
extension UIButton {
    func setTitleWithOutAnimation(title: String?) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

        setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)

        layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

Works for me on iOS 8 and 9, with `UIButtonTypeSystem`.

Comment: Works for me also with latest Swift release.  Also using UIButtonTypeSystem in IB.  Thanks!

Comment: Tested on Swift 3.1, still works!

Comment: This disables animations for the whole app just to not animate a button... it works, but it would be better to just use the custom UIButton type.

Answer (score 12):

You can perform Button changes inside the closure:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    //Button changes
    button.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Too bad, same result.

Comment: Also, it's shorter to call
UIView.performWithoutAnimation { //Button changes } You still need to call layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: I find this the correct answer!

Comment: The layoutIfNeeded after setting the setTitle call is all that's required.  Wrapping it in UIView.performWithoutAnimation doesn't seem to do anything here.